# Is there a statistical correction that works if the number of experiments depends on the result of the experiments?

Tags: p-value, sequential-analysis

Suppose that I am running an experiment that gives us some confidence $c$ about a hypothesis.

If I intend to run the experiment $n$ times, I understand there are some ways of choosing a $c'$ so that the chance of any experiment giving us a confidence of $c'$ had it been run alone implies a confidence of $c$ for the hypothesis.

What if I intend to run the experiment until my hypothesis is confirmed with a confidence of $c$? Is there a way to choose $c_i$ for each successive experiment to ensure that I am not "cheating"?

This question is about the difference if any between deciding to run an experiment $n$ times and deciding to run an experiment until the data supports a conclusion.  In other words, the decision to observe more data depends on past data.

A concrete example: suppose a researcher runs an experiment wanting to achieve a p-value of 0.05.  Suppose instead that he runs the experiment ten times.  He might apply a Bonferroni correction and expect a p-value of 0.005.  What if instead, after the first failure, he he runs it again with a p-value threshold of 0.025.  It fails, so he runs it again with a threshold of 0.05/3, and so on, until the experiment meets the threshold.  Is this fair?

Comment: What do you mean by "confidence"? Are you talking about p-values here?

Comment: @amoeba yes, but I didn't want to limit answers to only p-values.  I'm curious about this topic in general.

Comment: (tagged missing-data since this might be related to the *missing-at-random* assumption)

Comment: I am not sure a "general" answer is possible. I asked because you have [p-value] as a tag (but do not have [bayesian] as a tag, for example). In general, "confidence" is not a well-defined term. So I am not upvoting because I don't understand the question :)

Comment: @amoeba I have added a concrete example, but I'm not sure if it makes sense.

Comment: The example makes complete sense to me. Consider replacing "number of trials" with "number of experiments" in the title...

Comment: You may be looking for group-sequential methods or adaptive designs - or is there something that makes then non-applicable?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for [sequential analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sequential_analysis).